# Change name of the 'current_user' helper in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a `Client` model setup with Devise, and I've namespaced the routes like this:

```
  namespace :portal do
    devise_for :clients, controllers: {
        sessions: 'clients/sessions',
        registrations: 'clients/registrations',
        invitations: 'clients/invitations'
    } 
   end
```

Because of this, instead of a `current_client` helper I get `current_portal_client`. Is there a way I can set it to `current_client`? Should I just alias it in ApplicationController or is there a Devise specific way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Devise builds those methods on the fly and adds them to `ActiveSupport` on load. See line 132 here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb, so overriding the default functionality might be tricky and could get ugly fast.

Since Devise doesn't appear to offer any easily configurable overrides, you're probably better off writing an alias method in your `ApplicationController` as you suggested.